# How do I limit JPQ output?

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6, jpql

I need to limit number of entities returned by a query to some certain value inside a JPA query (through JPQL). Particularly:

```
select m from Manual m //constraint
```

e.g. in sql (mysql syntax) I would do it like:

```
select * from Manual limit 1
```

The only solution that comes up is simply to get all entities and then choose first one, which is out of the question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that I may limit Query instance, as follows:

```
em.createQuery("select m from Manual m").setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult()
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the part 'which makes constraints like "order by" unnecessary' is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, obviously irrelevant in current scope.